# Unexpected FormatException

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to delete items from a list, however I want the page to display a message "there are not items left in the catalogue" once all items have been deleted.
My try/catch code seems to work, however I receive an error FormatException was unhandled by usercode for the  [int id = Int32.Parse(txtID.Text);] line of code.

I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
    public partial class DeleteBook : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    public Catalogue catalogueInstance = new Catalogue();

    //Filepath for json file
    const string FILENAME = 
    @"C:\Users\tstra\Desktop\19456932_CSE2ICX_Assessment_3\Bin\Books.json";


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string jsonText = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);



    // reading data contained in the json filepath

    //convert objects in json file to lists
    catalogueInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Catalogue>(jsonText);

    if (IsPostBack) return;

    ddlDelete.DataSource = catalogueInstance.books;
    ddlDelete.DataTextField = "title";
    ddlDelete.DataValueField = "id";

    //binding the data to Drop Down List
    ddlDelete.DataBind();
   }

   protected void ddlDelete_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Book b = catalogueInstance.books[ddlDelete.SelectedIndex];
    txtID.Text = b.id.ToString();
    txtTitle.Text = b.title;
    txtAuthor.Text = b.author;
    txtYear.Text = b.year.ToString();
    txtPublisher.Text = b.publisher;
    txtISBN.Text = b.isbn;
    }

    protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
    int id = Int32.Parse(txtID.Text);
    Book book = catalogueInstance.books.SingleOrDefault(b => b.id == id);
    //catalogueInstance.books.Remove(book);

    catalogueInstance.books.RemoveAt(ddlDelete.SelectedIndex);

    ddlDelete.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlDelete_SelectedIndexChanged(ddlDelete, new EventArgs());

    if (book != null)
    {

    book.title = txtTitle.Text;
    book.year = Int32.Parse(txtYear.Text);
    book.author = txtAuthor.Text;
    book.publisher = txtPublisher.Text;
    book.isbn = txtISBN.Text;

    string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(catalogueInstance);
    File.WriteAllText(FILENAME, jsonText);
    }
    txtSummary.Text = "Book ID of " + id + " has Been deleted from the 
    Catalogue" + Environment.NewLine;

    try
    {
        File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {

        txtSummary.Text = "There are no items in the Catalogue";

    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: The title and start of your question talks about one thing, then you go my actual problem is something else. just thought id let you know

Comment: Most people on here are not going to bother reading your wall of code.  Please provide a *minimal*, *complete* and *verifyable* example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: So what is in the text box when you click the delete button?

Comment: what is value of `txtID.Text` ?

Comment: That `txtID.Text`, at some point, is definitely not an integer. Wrap it in a `try{ } catch(FormatException e){ Console.log($"{textID.Text} is not an integer")}` to see what the value. That should help you figure out a better way of handling it

Answer (score 4):

Its seems this question boils down to parsing an int

[Int32.Parse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent.
>
> **FormatException**   : Value is not in the correct format.

You need to be more defensive, textboxes can contain anything, users can type anything

Always try to use [`Int32.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation
>   succeeded.

**Example**

```
bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
if (result)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);         
}
else
{ 
   Console.WriteLine("Attempted conversion of '{0}' failed.", 
                           value == null ? "<null>" : value);
}
```

This is all to say, if you are going to parse something, its best to be defensive about it.

Also debugging is a vital tool for writing software. You could have probably worked out and solved your problem by examining your code while its running. You might want to have a read through the following

[Navigating through Code with the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)

[Using Breakpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx)

**Update**

For a more solution centric example, anywhere you use something like this

```
int id = Int32.Parse(txtID.Text);
```

You should really do something like this

```
int id;

if(!Int32.TryParse(txtID.Text, out Id))
{
   //Let the user know about the in correct values
   // example
   MessageBox.Show("hmmMMm, Entered the wrong value you have, Fix it you must - Yoda");
   return;
}
```

Comment: also explain how OP can use it in his code, Coz, I think more he will need to fix his TextBox's value (it must not be other than numerical) , than implementing `TryParse` .

Comment: @Amit, nice to see you again, yup will modify soon

Comment: +1, this is exactly what I was saying, nicely handled by not allowing any further logic if textbox is not holding proper data for year.

Comment: Thank guys, you have been a great help. Starting to understand now.